# javascript- How to display html content in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I want to display HTML content in a text box, but I am stuck.
Here is my code, which is working fine when I displayed the text into label. But its not working for text box.

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="showDiv"></div>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
function myfun(){
    var item="<span class="kwcat">results in <b>(.*?)</b></span>";
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.setAttribute("id", "myid");
    div2.setAttribute("class","inner");
    value2= replaceAll(item, '<','&lt;');
    value2=replaceAll(value2, '>','&gt;');

    var comp= '<div>';  
    comp += '<label >';
    comp += "Heading: ";
    comp += '</label>';

    /* comp += '<input type="text" value=' + value2 + '>'; */

    comp += '<label>';
    comp += value2;
    comp +='</label>';
    comp += '</div>';
    div2.innerHTML = comp;
    showDiv.appendChild(div2);
}
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

The line which I have commented, is what I want to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you need to wrap the value in quotes as well

Comment: Maybe you need richtext editor.

Comment: why are you setting the id of the attribute as a span element

Comment: @Toxide82.. i edited id.

Comment: does that work now, you also need to change kwcat quotes to 'kwcat'  not "kwcat"

Comment: @Toxido82, not working.
I can't change the "kwcat" quotes to 'kwcat' .Actually I have a list of such `item` values. And for all of them i am running this function. If I `replace` `" "` with `' '`, it may be the case that some item value have data with just one quote `"` and if i am replacing `" ` with `'` , in this case i'll loose data. 
I hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input value in quotes as well

```
function myfun(){
 var item="<span class=\"kwcat\">results in <b>(.*?)</b></span>";
 var div2 = document.createElement('div');
 div2.setAttribute("id", "myid");
 div2.setAttribute("class","inner");
 value2= replaceAll(item, '<','&lt;');
 value2=replaceAll(value2, '>','&gt;');

 var  comp= '<div>'+  
       '<label>Heading:</label>'+
       '<textarea>'+ value2 + '</textarea>'+
       '<label>'+value2+'</label>'+
       '</div>';

 div2.innerHTML = comp;
 showDiv.appendChild(div2);
}
```

your function should look like the above

Comment: why are you adding forward slashes before the class quotes? - just change for single instead of double

Comment: yeah I know, how it should be. I already said in my question that its working properly for label. The problem is with textbox display.

Comment: try it with a textarea instead of an input - Modified answer for this

Comment: it worked for the given item value `<span class=\"kwcat\">results in <b>(.*?)</b></span>` but it failed for this one `cre\n_compile\np0\n(V<span class=\"kwcat\">results in <b>(.*?)</b></span>\np1\nI18\ntp2\nRp3\n.`

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap the value in quotes

```
comp += '<input type="text" value="' + value2 + '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

- Encode double quotes, By replacing **"** with **"**

> value2=replaceAll(value2, '"','"');

- Surround the value of attribute of input data type with double quotes

> `comp += <input type="text" value="' + value2 + '">';`

Now you have your input field value as the same value of item variable